# Relation between composition series of modules over $R[G]$ and composition series of a group $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Let $A$ be a finite-dimensional algebra over a field $F$ and $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $F$. A linear mapping $f\colon V\otimes_F A\to V$ determines on $V$ some $A$-module structure if the corresponding operation is associative and $1\otimes v\mapsto v$ for any $v\in V$.

It is possible to show that for such modules finite composition series exists.

Now let's try to study the case of modules over $F[G]$ for a finite group $G$. Assume $V$ be some finite-dimensional vector space over $F$ and $f$ be a $F$-algebras homomorphism $F[G]\to \operatorname{End}_F(V)$. Now we define an operation $V\otimes_F F[G]\to V$ as $v\otimes g\mapsto (f(g))(v)$.

Is that possible to chose $V$ and $f$ in order to obtain classical Jordan-Holder theorem (for any finite group $G$ there exists a composition series)? If it is, is there any correspondence between composition series of a module and a group?

Thanks for paying attention.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez existence of the composition series for any finite group

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez it's all about connections, not for practice. Just for interest.

Comment: Do you require modules to be associative and unital (i.e., $a(bm) = (ab)m$ and $1 ⋅ m = m$ for all $a, b, m$)? If so, then the first paragraph is wrong, as you’ll need some additional requirements on the linear map $f$.